# Cycle Windows in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a keyboard shortcut for cycling through just Outlook 2010 windows on Windows 7? Some equivalent to <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> for Firefox on OS X.

I didn't see it on the official keyboard shortcut list: https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HP003084223.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>? That's usually the child-window switching keystroke.

Comment: With two windows open in Outlook, Ctrl-Tab doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> should work, although it's not exactly finger-friendly.

Comment: I am on Windows, but this keyboard shortcut doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: I've only tested it on Windows XP so it's possible that it was dropped for Windows 7.  Is Outlook focused and does it have multiple windows open?

Comment: Yes, Outlook is focused, and it has two windows open. Nothing happened.